# Method in class category works not as instance method

Tags: ios, objective-c-category

In my project I have two `NSManageObjects` (Core Data generated). For both objects I have created a category with an instance method called `containsToday`.

The problem is that only the method for the object `ListElement` works. While calling the method for the object `NamedRange` I get (same method as class method works):

> -[NSManagedObject containsToday]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

Here is some code:

ListElement:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class ListImage, TLList;

@interface ListElement : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * agn;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * aid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * iid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * indx;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * mark;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * oid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * tcd;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * cxl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * oti;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ListImage *listImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TLList *tlList;

@end
```

NamedRange:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface NamedRange : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * tid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sta;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * end;

@end
```

ListElement (Additions):

```
#import "ListElement.h"

@interface ListElement (Additions)

- (BOOL) containsToday;

@end
```

NamedRange (Additions):

```
#import "NamedRange.h"

@interface NamedRange (Additions)

#warning TODO - why does this not work as instance method (for ListElement it works)?
+ (BOOL) containsToday:(NamedRange*)nr;
- (BOOL) containsToday;
@end
```

Comment: `+` methods are class methods. To use these you would have to do `[NamedRange containsToday:object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't set the Entity Class in the data model correctly. The message indicates that it's attempting to call the method on an object of class `NSManagedObject`, not an instance of your derived class.

In XCode, open up your data model, select the ListElement entity, then open the Data Model Inspector on the right hand side (in the Utilities bar) and check that the Entity Class is correct. If I'm correct, I think you'll find it's currently still set to NSManagedObject.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. No class set for 'NamedRange'